# Mysql workbench can connect to remote database even the server has closed the port

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

When I'm trying to use IDEA to connect the remote MySQL database, it always tips me "connection timed out". When I open the port, I can use idea to connect remote MySQL database. That's great, but I wonder that why the MySQL workbench can connect to the remote MySQL database without opening the specific server port?

I try to close the port and the IDEA fail to connect to the database. But the MySQL workbench still can connect to the remote database without any obstacle.

Comment: Impossible, it might be cache in workbench, try to disconnect and connect again

Comment: Could it be that a protocol other than TCP/IP is used for db connection in Workbench?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/transport-protocols.html

Comment: Thanks to the comment, as a green hands, I don't know whether overflow can reply to the comments. But after I change the other port to map the mysql docker 3306 port, when I close the specific port, mysql workbench also cannot connect to the remote server. This may be caused by my previous miss operation. Anyway, thanks guys.